Python list to feed a selection Or clause
If I have a python list that I want to generate a selection clause from.  How do I do this elegantly?
Example list:
fruit = ['apple', 'blackberry', 'peach', 'kiwi']

and I want a resultant SQL clause string variable set like:
item_field = 'apple' Or item_field = 'blackberry' Or item_field = 'peach' Or item_field = 'kiwi'

I have tried a few things ("item_field = {}".format(' Or '.join(fruit))  -- somewhat close) and Googled, but just not getting what I am looking for.

This "resultant clause variable" thing, what is it supposed to be exactly? A string? Very unclear... [ask] and [mre]

What's the result supposed to be for? An SQL clause? Then depending on your exact database and driver, you'd be using something like cursor.execute('SELECT ... WHERE item_field IN %s', (fruit,))…

If you are looking for a string, then this is an easy solution:
" Or ".join(f"item_field = '{fruit}'" for fruit in fruits)


I'm assuming that by resultant clause variable you mean a string. If so this may be achieved by:
fruits = ['apple', 'blackberry', 'peach', 'kiwi']
clause = " Or ".join(["item_field = {}".format(fruit) for fruit in fruits])

Edited to follow @Julien's suggestion

This is more complicated than necessary and is missing quotes...

@Julien To be fair, manually adding quotes here is risky to begin with. Unless that's a static list of values, you're risking some sort of injection/invalid syntax with this approach, depending on where the result will actually be used…
